# How to get last value for every partition to impute missing value in spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a sample data where I want to impute the missing values. The rows where the data is missing is denoted by `blank`. Here is the sample data -

```
val my_df = spark.sql(s"""
select 1 as id, 1 as time_gmt, 'a' as pagename
union
select 1 as id, 2 as time_gmt, 'b' as pagename
union
select 1 as id, 3 as time_gmt, 'blank' as pagename
union
select 1 as id, 4 as time_gmt, 'blank' as pagename
union
select 1 as id, 5 as time_gmt, 'd' as pagename
union
select 2 as id, 1 as time_gmt, 'c' as pagename
union
select 2 as id, 2 as time_gmt, 'a' as pagename
union
select 2 as id, 3 as time_gmt, 'c' as pagename
union
select 2 as id, 4 as time_gmt, 'blank' as pagename
union
select 2 as id, 5 as time_gmt, 'd' as pagename
""")
my_df.createOrReplaceTempView("my_df")

scala> my_df.orderBy("id","time_gmt").show(false)
+---+--------+--------+
|id |time_gmt|pagename|
+---+--------+--------+
|1  |1       |a       |
|1  |2       |b       |
|1  |3       |blank   |
|1  |4       |blank   |
|1  |5       |d       |
|2  |1       |c       |
|2  |2       |a       |
|2  |3       |c       |
|2  |4       |blank   |
|2  |5       |d       |
+---+--------+--------+
```

As you can see, there are 2 blanks for data with id 1 and 1 blank for data with id 2. I want to fill in those values using the latest non-blank value observed for each ID, ordered by `time_gmt` column. So my output would be -

```
+---+--------+--------+----------------+
|id |time_gmt|pagename|pagename_imputed|
+---+--------+--------+----------------+
|1  |1       |a       | a              | 
|1  |2       |b       | b              | 
|1  |3       |blank   | b              | 
|1  |4       |blank   | b              |
|1  |5       |d       | d              | 
|2  |1       |c       | c              | 
|2  |2       |a       | a              | 
|2  |3       |c       | c              | 
|2  |4       |blank   | c              | 
|2  |5       |d       | d              | 
+---+--------+--------+----------------+
```

How can I do this in spark SQL ?

NOTE -  the blanks can appear multiple times for every partition after non-blank values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option uses window functions. The idea is to define groups of record, where "blank" records will belong to the same group as the last non-blank.

Assuming that by *blank* you mean `null`, we can define the groups with a window count:

```
select id, time_gmt, 
    max(pagename) over(partition by id, grp) as pagename
from (
    select t.*, 
        count(pagename) over(partition by id order by time_gmt) as grp
    from mytable t
) t
```

If you really mean string `'blank'`, then:

```
select id, time_gmt, 
    max(case when pagename <> 'blank' then pagename end) over(partition by id, grp) as pagename
from (
    select t.*, 
        sum(case when pagename = 'blank' then 0 else 1 end) over(partition by id order by time_gmt) as grp
    from mytable t
) t
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the solution. yes i meant string 'blank'. But when i used ur second solution, I could not get the answer as intended. Only ID 2 got imputed while ID had 3 blank records after ur query

Comment: @Regressor: ah yes, I see the problem. The outer window function needs to be adapted to properly handle "blank" too. Done.

Comment: awesome solution to create groups based on `sum()..` function. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a special window function `last(expr, [IgnoreNulls]) over()` for such use cases:

```
select id, time_gmt, last(nullif(pagename, 'blank'), true) over(partition by id order by time_gmt) as pagename
from my_df
```

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#last